# Iterator going overbound and causing seg fault

Tags: c++, iterator

So I have an iterator iterating through a map with int as key and a custome object as value. While iterating through this map, the iterator always go over the amount of elements stored in the map. I fixed this by forcing the loop to stop when a counter value becomes bigger than the size of the map, but I am quite confused as to why I need to do that (I am pretty sure the solution just defeats the point of an iterator). Here's the section of the code causing problem. `Patrons`, `Address` and `Library` are all predefined class that are working (since the values print out normally).

```
map<int, Patron>::iterator it;
        int counter = 0;
        for(it = library.getPatrons().getPatrons().begin(); it != library.getPatrons().getPatrons().end() && counter < library.getPatrons().getPatrons().size(); ++it){
            cout << library.getPatrons().getPatrons().size() << endl;
            cout << it->second.getName() << endl;
            cout << it->second.getAddress().getStreetAddress() << endl;
            cout << it->second.getAddress().getCity() << ", " <<  it->second.getAddress().getState() << " " << it->second.getAddress().getZip() << endl;
            counter++;
            cout << endl;
        }
```

if this loop is iterating through a one element map, without the `counter < library.getPatrons().getPatrons().size()` check, the following are outputed:

```
1 //the size of the map
sdfoji //the name of the owner of the address
sdfio //the street address
sdfio, oifds 77494 //the city, state, and zip code

1
sdfoji
sdfio
sdfio, oifds 77494

1
//seg fault here
```

as you can see, the iterator iterated through 2 non existent value, seemingly ignoring the condition `it != library.getPatrons().getPatrons().end()`

Comment: Does `library.getPatrons().getPatrons()` return a new map each time it's called?

Comment: what do you mean by a new map?

Comment: I mean a new `map<int, Patron>`, as opposed to a reference to the same `map<int, Patron>` each time.

Comment: Yes. Looking at the comment below I realized that I am returning map by value and not by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop does not clearly answer what's wrong. Most likely one of your `getPatrons()` methods return map by value and you end up comparing your iterator to `end()` that belongs to another instance of map and for that reason your iteration will always run out of bounds.

Here's easy fix to verify my guess:

```
map<int, Patron>::iterator it;
int counter = 0;
map<int, Patron> patrons = library.getPatrons().getPatrons();
for (it = patrons.begin(); it != patrons.end(); ++it) {
    cout << patrons.size() << endl;
    cout << it->second.getName() << endl;
    cout << it->second.getAddress().getStreetAddress() << endl;
    cout << it->second.getAddress().getCity() << ", " << it->second.getAddress().getState() << " " << it->second.getAddress().getZip() << endl;
    counter++;
    cout << endl;
}
```

If this fixes your problem you should change the function to return by reference (cosnt reference) or you may as well use [range-based for-loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) which would not have this problem even if you return map by value:

```
int counter = 0;
for (const auto& it : library.getPatrons().getPatrons()) {
    cout << it.second.getName() << endl;
    cout << it.second.getAddress().getStreetAddress() << endl;
    cout << it.second.getAddress().getCity() << ", " << it.second.getAddress().getState() << " " << it.second.getAddress().getZip() << endl;
    counter++;
    cout << endl;
}
```